# Running a PowerShell script concurrently - Limitation on instances?

Tags: powershell

Is there a limit on how many instances of a single PowerShell script can be run in parallel?

I have multiple scheduled tasks setup to run a PowerShell script with different parameter values at the same time every day, however, appears 3 of the 10 tasks that ran at the same time didn't complete fully which makes me wonder if there's limit?

Comment: You can run as many `powershell.exe` process instances as the OS has resources for. Please include the code + describe the observed behavior if you want help figuring out what's going on :-)

Comment: You may also be running into issues with data structures that are not thread safe., or using resources that have lock-based controls like file access on Windows or records in a pessimistic RDBMS. As mentioned above, without the code being executed any answer beyond, "Yes, that behavior is possible," is pure speculation.

Comment: The script is quite complex but as mentioned, running this at the same time does work up to a certain number of concurrent sessions so don't think there's anything within the code that's causing this. The process is grabbing files from remote servers and compressing/uploading to SFTP and archiving etc. Going by the log output for each job, it's around 7-8 concurrent jobs before it stops processing. I'm guessing that this is a resource issue then as it's random with which job it doesn't run. A log is created but it's empty. I'll set them to run in batches of 4 and see what happens to confirm.

Comment: Having split this up to run 4 concurrent instances at any one time, it's now running successfully for all. I know compression can eat system resources so dare say giving the server more CPU would assist here, however, running batches of 4 every 5 minutes isn't an issue. My initial question was answered so am happy to put this one to rest. Many thanks @MathiasR.Jessen.